# Is it normal to have a lot of Failed In App Purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I just published my Android application in Google Play for the very first time, but after a while, in my merchant account, there are a lot of canceled orders.

And all of them was the same reason `Customer's Credit Card was declined`

I have some questions regarding this issue

1- Is it quite normal that to have canceled purchases?

2- What could be the reason for cancellation?

I really can't find any helpful information according to this issue.

Anything regarding this issue will be great.

Comment: may be user just navigated to payment screen and then just navigated back??

Comment: @VivekMishra in order history it says "You have a new order" then google canceled it. I don't think so it could be the reason because it clearly says
"Customer's Credit Card was declined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- Is it quite normal that to have canceled purchases?

It's allright. If there is something wrong Google payment gateway will handle it. If there is something really weird and needs a fix at your end you will get a notification from google regarding it.

> 2- What could be the reason of cancellation?

Sometimes this happens when the app is tested or reviewed by the appstores (manually or using automated scripts). The cards used by the testers or services are generally dummy and may cause this. I always get a lot those when i submit my app in Samsung store.

Comment: Recently I got two cancellation from same location is Australia.
I didn't send any update or any thing
Can you please explain this

Comment: then someone is fooling around with the app. or may be entered the wrong card details twice by mistake. (probably an expired card which was saved with google). I would not worry much. You have nothing to lose with someone making invalid attempts.

Comment: what if card is successfully charged, order delivered, but after immediately user cancelled the order?